# How to use enums to define constant value groups

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, interface, enums, constants

im using interface to accesses the project constant
this is my interface

```
public interface ConstantValues {

    interface PaymentType   {
        public static final String CREDIT_CUSTOMER = "credit";
        public static final String CASH_CUSTOMER = "cash";
    }

    interface PaymentMethode    {
        public static final String CREDIT_CARD = "creditcard";
        public static final String VISA_CARD = "visacard";
        public static final String MASTER_CARD = "mastercard";
    }

}
```

im accessing this values form the java class like in the below

```
 ConstantValues.PaymentType.CREDIT_CUSTOMER

 or

 ConstantValues.PaymentType.VISA_CARD
```

but i want to know how to do this using enum, because using a 
interfaces to define constant is bad practice can please anybody
tell me how to do that using enum and how to access it from java class?

Comment: Do you know how to declare an `enum` and its constants? Other than that, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Have you read the tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: +1 for recognizing it is bad practice. many people still do this

Comment: im completely new to java, i haven't used enums

Comment: It is important to understand why it is a bad practise. When you materialize a constant into an `Enum`, you are giving it context through your entire codebase, you have an instance of a known and documented type, which has a specific purpose. With a string constant, you must add context to it every time you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
enum PaymentType   {
    CREDIT_CUSTOMER,
    CASH_CUSTOMER;
}

enum PaymentMethod    {
    CREDIT_CARD,
    VISA_CARD,
    MASTER_CARD;
}
```

Use it like:

`PaymentMethod meth = PaymentMethod.VISA_CARD;`

etc.

Comment: how do u define the values for those constant?

Comment: the point of an enum is you dont have to do that kind of stuff. You can test for equality with == just like reference comparison.

Comment: @user2567005 The constant is the value.

Comment: thanks mate but i have put the enum declaration inside a class so that i don't have to create more than one enum. is it bad?

Comment: No, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Enums {
    public enum Test {
        FIRST,
        SECOND,
        THIRD
    }

    public enum Test2 {
        FIRST("first"),
        SECOND("second"),
        THIRD("third");

        private final String value;

        Test2(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Enums.Test.FIRST);
        System.out.println(Enums.Test2.FIRST.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do u define the values for the enum Test?

Comment: They are values by their nature, you could use them like:
Test t = Test.FIRST or
String s = Test.FIRST.name()